# Java TCP SO_RESUEADDR, cannot connect

Tags: java, tcp, p2p

I don't know how to clearly describe my question in title, as for me it is a little complicated. What i am doing is try to implement a TCP peer to peer demo, in which a local port must be both for listening and initiating a socket.

I will give a detailed description.
I will give a java implementation which will listen and initiate connection on a single local port. Code will explain my idea.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Just for testing socket SO_RESUEADDR. If set SO_RESUEADDR to true, we can use
 * a single local port to listen for incoming TCP connections, and to initiate
 * multiple outgoing TCP connections concurrently. By this way we can implement
 * TCP hole punching(establish P2P connection traversal through NAT over TCP).
 */
public class TcpPeer {
    // TCP port is a different source from UDP port, it means you can listen on
    // same port for both TCP and UDP at the same time.
    private int localport = 7890;
    private ServerSocket peerSock;
    private Socket serverSocket;

    public TcpPeer(final String serverHost, final int serverPort, final int localPort)
        throws Exception {
    this.localport = localPort;

    Thread server = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                peerSock = new ServerSocket();
                peerSock.setReuseAddress(true);
                peerSock.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", localport));
                System.out.println("[Server]The server is listening on " + localport + ".");

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        serverSocket = peerSock.accept();
                        // just means finishing handshaking, and connection
                        // established.
                        System.out.println("[Server]New connection accepted"
                                + serverSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + serverSocket.getPort());

                        BufferedReader br = getReader(serverSocket);
                        PrintWriter pw = getWriter(serverSocket);
                        String req = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("[Server][REQ]" + req);
                        pw.println(req);

                        pw.close();
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (serverSocket != null)
                                serverSocket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    // server.setDaemon(true);
    server.start();

    Thread.currentThread();
    // sleep several seconds before launch of client
    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

    final int retry = 5;
    Thread client = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            try {
                socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                System.out.println("[Client]socket.isBound():" + socket.isBound());
                socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", localport));
                for (int i = 1; i < retry; i++) {
                    try {
                        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverHost, serverPort));
                        System.out.println("[Client]connect to " + serverHost + ":"
                                + serverPort + " successfully.");
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("[Client]fail to connect " + serverHost + ":"
                                + serverPort + ", try again.");
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(i * 2 * 1000);
            if (i == retry - 1) return; 
                    }
                }

                PrintWriter pw = getWriter(socket);
                String msg = "hello world!";
                pw.println(msg);

                /**
                 * Got response from the server socket.
                 */
                BufferedReader br = getReader(socket);
                String resp = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("[Client][RESP-1]" + resp);

                pw.close();
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    });
    client.start();
}

private PrintWriter getWriter(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    OutputStream socketOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    return new PrintWriter(socketOut, true);
}

private BufferedReader getReader(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    InputStream socketIn = socket.getInputStream();
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketIn));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.out.println("[Usage] java " + TcpPeer.class.getCanonicalName()
                + " [serverHost] [serverPort] [localPort]");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    new TcpPeer(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
}
}
```

Now we launch 2 jvm processes:

```
ps#1> java TcpPeer localhost 2000 4000
ps#2> java TcpPeer localhost 4000 2000
```

Finally when 2 processes got stable, they will give below outputs:

ps#1>

```
[Server]The server is listening on 2000.
[Client]socket.isBound():false
[Client]connect to localhost:4000 successfully.
[Client][RESP-1]hello world!
```

ps#2>

```
[Server]The server is listening on 4000.
[Server]New connection accepted/127.0.0.1:2000
[Server][REQ]hello world!
[Client]socket.isBound():false
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
    at org.clinic4j.net.TcpPeer$2.run(TcpPeer.java:92)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[Client]fail to connect localhost:2000, try again.
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
    at org.clinic4j.net.TcpPeer$2.run(TcpPeer.java:92)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[Client]fail to connect localhost:2000, try again.
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
    at org.clinic4j.net.TcpPeer$2.run(TcpPeer.java:92)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[Client]fail to connect localhost:2000, try again.
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
    at org.clinic4j.net.TcpPeer$2.run(TcpPeer.java:92)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[Client]fail to connect localhost:2000, try again.
```

From the output, we can figure out that interaction flow as below:

1. ps#1 listen on 2000.
2. ps#2 listen on 4000.
3. ps#1 connect to ps#2, from localhost:2000 -> localhost:4000.
4. ps#2 close the connection which established at step#3.
5. ps#2 try to connect to ps#1 at 2000, failed!

Why ps#2 cannot connect to ps#1 at step#4?  I also monitor the net status of OS.

Below is net status right after step#3.
[image]

And also the net status right after step#4.
[image]

- 192.168.2.107 is localhost

Could you please give me a comment on my case? thanks!

> I have printed out the original exception message when fail to reconnect, but i don't have much idea about those exception.

Comment: "A local port must be both for listening and initiating a socket." Why?

Comment: I read the paper [Peer-to-Peer Communication Across Network Address Translators](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/), and just try to establish a P2P TCP connection across NAT.

Comment: Hi Ramon, Stuck in a similar situation. Did you ever figure out the solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't bind the client socket, and also not set the `SO_REUSEADDR` on client socket.

If you do not bind a client socket, the system will automatically assign a port number for you.

Also, `SO_REUSEADDR` doesn't mean the address (ip/port numbers) can be reused while the socket is still open. It's so that when a socket has been closed and is in the `TIME_WAIT` state, you can bind to that again.

Comment: As I want to implement a demo which demonstrate STUN on TCP(establish TCP connection across NAT), the client socket must be bound to the same port with the server socket...I just wonder why step#5 will fail, actually i don't have a good background on network knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your client thread exits just after the first exchange of messages, it lacks `while(true)` part.

Comment: As he's not even getting that far the point is moot. Not an answer.

Comment: @EJP According to OP log client prints `[RESP-1]hello world!` to console. From code it seems client entered `Thread#run()` , but this method isn't looped, so only one exchange of messages is possible per one client instance.

Comment: Yeah. It seems like he isn't properly closing the first client socket so he can't create the second one bound to the same port.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you get through your connection retries without a successful connection you need to quit, not fall through into the I/O code. This is why you are getting the actual exception.
2. You also need to print out *why* the connections are failing. At the moment this is the most important information, and you are suppressing it. Print the exception message. This is a general principle: don't make up your own message, use the one you're given. It is almost certainly more specific.
3. Instead of new InetAddress("localhost") use `null` when binding the ServerSocket.
4. I'm not convinced that you can retry a connect on a socket. If it fails, try creating a new Socket.

Comment: #2. I have called e.printStackTrace() to print the original exception message every time when catch a exception...oh ic, you mean the try-catch in for loop.

Comment: @Ramon I mean everywhere. I also mean that you should post the resulting exception here so that we can analyze it. Or is it really such a secret that you need to keep it secret from yourself?